# Prove area under Lebesgue integrable function above $c$ can be made arbitrarily small with large enough $c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a nonnegative Lebesgue integrable function on $[0,1]$. Denote by $m$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Prove that for reach $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $c >0$ such that $$\int_{\{ x \in [0,1] : f(x) \geq c\} } f dm < \epsilon.$$

Attempted Proof: By way of contradiction, letting $_c=\{x∈[0,1]:()\geq c\}$, for any $c$ we have that
$$ \int_{[0,1] } f \geq \int_{E_c} f \geq c \cdot m (E_c) \geq c \cdot m (E)$$
where $E = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$.

The problem is that $m(E)$ cannot be bounded below by a positive quantity, so I cannot make the integral arbitrarily large.

Comment: Did you post this before?

Comment: Apply dominated convergence: $\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}f(x)\mathbb{1}_{\{|f|>c\}}(x)=0$ unless $|f(x)|=0$. Since $f$ is integrable, $\||f|=\infty\}$ has mastered $0$.

Comment: And $E$ is irrelevant. You should show that for some $c>0$, $m(E_c)<\epsilon.$ You get that directly from $\int_{E_c} f \geq c \cdot m (E_c)$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yes, but the original did not include my attempted proof. How does showing $m(E_c) < \epsilon$ help?

Comment: You are right, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a version of Mitten's comment:

By possibly changing the values on a null set, we can assume that $f(x)$ is a real number for all $x\in[0,1]$.  We have $$\int f~ \mathrm d m=\int_{[0,1]\setminus E_c} f~ \mathrm d m+\int_{E_c} f \mathrm d m.$$
Also, $\lim_{c\to\infty} 1_{[0,1]\setminus E_c} f(x)=f(x)$.
By the dominated convergence theorem,
$$\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]\setminus E_c} f~ \mathrm d m=\int f~ \mathrm dm.$$
So $$\lim_{c\to\infty}\int_{E_c} f~ \mathrm d m=\lim_{c\to\infty}\bigg(\int f~ \mathrm dm-\int_{[0,1]\setminus E_c} f~ \mathrm d m\bigg)=0.$$

Comment: This makes sense. The monotone convergence theorem works equally well, correct?

Comment: Yes, it does the job too.

Answer (score 0):

I will write $\mu$ for the Lebesgue measure ( by way of habit) . Notice that as $f$ is positive and Lebesgue integrable the function $\nu: \mathcal{B}([0,1]) \rightarrow [0, \|f\|_{1} ] $ with:

$$ \nu(E) = \int_{E} f d\mu $$

is a finite measure absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Furthermore notice that:

$$ \mu(E_{c}) \rightarrow 0 $$

This is a direct consequence of Markov's inequality , where $E_{c}$ as in your post, thus using a well known lemmma (actually a characterization of absolute continuity), we have that for some $\delta > 0 $ if $\mu(E_{c}) < \delta$ we must have:

$$ \nu(E_{c}) < \varepsilon$$

which is exactly what you want to prove.

Comment: This seems correct, although I'm not sure that lemma was allowed to be assumed. (This was a qual exam question.)

Comment: I think its the first lemma one works through after the definition, see eg Folland, so I would assume it should be okay.

Comment: I would think so too, but don't want to take chances! :)